# how to select all "src" in below code for beautiful soup

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

this is the html code from which i want ot select all src ho can i select all src

```
<div class="thumbnails-wrapper" style="display: inline-block; visibility: visible;">
<div class="thumbnails" data-expand-target="thumbnails">
<span class="details-trailer">
<span class="video-image-wrapper">
<span class="preview-overlay-container" data-video-url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lXaGPCSqlsM?ps=play&vq=large&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&authuser=0" data-docid="com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftAGHM">
</span>
<img class="screenshot clickable" tabindex="0" itemprop="screenshot" title=" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail " alt=" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail " src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/x7dX056Uo1zlIsTx1rN2NO19g3ETS2J-8A6rmrypc-k_VPdMY5hnoFSVS-MENXfUfqBL=h310" data-expand-to="full-screenshot-0">
<img class="screenshot clickable" tabindex="0" itemprop="screenshot" title=" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail " alt=" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail " src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/iXwUtiXyragrVn6BeQq2OFFeNR0z1JJVaNELuQscWlizBiwn-dGO1Jb9T8UO29NW2DI=h310" data-expand-to="full-screenshot-1">
<img class="screenshot clickable" tabindex="0" itemprop="screenshot" title=" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail " alt=" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail " src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/ueH3VEOiN414QwlDUtoRE4-xyV1ucHF3puKRXHtMeJFrkqrlAeC_OcVHV3JKGYiKC8A=h310" data-expand-to="full-screenshot-2">
<img class="screenshot clickable" tabindex="0" itemprop="screenshot" title=" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail " alt=" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail " src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/2VIXmIvny4xxbDVALMUumX4hdIM38P9OHp0PhT0ktFT7CyNcEX22QjpSsI6hQaWRYxM=h310" data-expand-to="full-screenshot-3">
<img class="screenshot clickable" tabindex="0" itemprop="screenshot" title=" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail " alt=" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail " src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/fxSqT5CXu1TmSS2MMjmPXnEXbzIMaBr2mlA3SdA1lRI3rr4IMwPUBHAvS4_UE1uXZN73=h310" data-expand-to="full-screenshot-4">
<img class="screenshot clickable" tabindex="0" itemprop="screenshot" title=" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: you question is little bit unclear, you want to extract the src field from all images ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for i in soup.select('.thumbnails-wrapper img'):
    print i['src']
```

or

```
print [i.get('src', None) for i in soup.select('.thumbnails-wrapper img')]
```

Comment: this code shows alll src on the page but a dont want those all "src" i want those src which are in thumbnails-wrapper" class

Comment: simple, check my update... You should mention this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'src="([^"]+)')
test_str = u"<div class=\"thumbnails-wrapper\" style=\"display: inline-block; visibility: visible;\">\n<div class=\"thumbnails\" data-expand-target=\"thumbnails\">\n<span class=\"details-trailer\">\n<span class=\"video-image-wrapper\">\n<span class=\"preview-overlay-container\" data-video-url=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/lXaGPCSqlsM?ps=play&vq=large&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&authuser=0\" data-docid=\"com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftAGHM\">\n</span>\n<img class=\"screenshot clickable\" tabindex=\"0\" itemprop=\"screenshot\" title=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" alt=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" src=\"//lh3.googleusercontent.com/x7dX056Uo1zlIsTx1rN2NO19g3ETS2J-8A6rmrypc-k_VPdMY5hnoFSVS-MENXfUfqBL=h310\" data-expand-to=\"full-screenshot-0\">\n<img class=\"screenshot clickable\" tabindex=\"0\" itemprop=\"screenshot\" title=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" alt=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" src=\"//lh3.googleusercontent.com/iXwUtiXyragrVn6BeQq2OFFeNR0z1JJVaNELuQscWlizBiwn-dGO1Jb9T8UO29NW2DI=h310\" data-expand-to=\"full-screenshot-1\">\n<img class=\"screenshot clickable\" tabindex=\"0\" itemprop=\"screenshot\" title=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" alt=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" src=\"//lh3.googleusercontent.com/ueH3VEOiN414QwlDUtoRE4-xyV1ucHF3puKRXHtMeJFrkqrlAeC_OcVHV3JKGYiKC8A=h310\" data-expand-to=\"full-screenshot-2\">\n<img class=\"screenshot clickable\" tabindex=\"0\" itemprop=\"screenshot\" title=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" alt=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" src=\"//lh3.googleusercontent.com/2VIXmIvny4xxbDVALMUumX4hdIM38P9OHp0PhT0ktFT7CyNcEX22QjpSsI6hQaWRYxM=h310\" data-expand-to=\"full-screenshot-3\">\n<img class=\"screenshot clickable\" tabindex=\"0\" itemprop=\"screenshot\" title=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" alt=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" src=\"//lh3.googleusercontent.com/fxSqT5CXu1TmSS2MMjmPXnEXbzIMaBr2mlA3SdA1lRI3rr4IMwPUBHAvS4_UE1uXZN73=h310\" data-expand-to=\"full-screenshot-4\">\n<img class=\"screenshot clickable\" tabindex=\"0\" itemprop=\"screenshot\" title=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail "

m = re.findall(p, test_str)
print m
```

Output:

```
[u'//lh3.googleusercontent.com/x7dX056Uo1zlIsTx1rN2NO19g3ETS2J-8A6rmrypc-k_VPdMY5hnoFSVS-MENXfUfqBL=h310', u'//lh3.googleusercontent.com/iXwUtiXyragrVn6BeQq2OFFeNR0z1JJVaNELuQscWlizBiwn-dGO1Jb9T8UO29NW2DI=h310', u'//lh3.googleusercontent.com/ueH3VEOiN414QwlDUtoRE4-xyV1ucHF3puKRXHtMeJFrkqrlAeC_OcVHV3JKGYiKC8A=h310', u'//lh3.googleusercontent.com/2VIXmIvny4xxbDVALMUumX4hdIM38P9OHp0PhT0ktFT7CyNcEX22QjpSsI6hQaWRYxM=h310', u'//lh3.googleusercontent.com/fxSqT5CXu1TmSS2MMjmPXnEXbzIMaBr2mlA3SdA1lRI3rr4IMwPUBHAvS4_UE1uXZN73=h310']
```

Use `BS4`

```
test_str = u"<div class=\"thumbnails-wrapper\" style=\"display: inline-block; visibility: visible;\">\n<div class=\"thumbnails\" data-expand-target=\"thumbnails\">\n<span class=\"details-trailer\">\n<span class=\"video-image-wrapper\">\n<span class=\"preview-overlay-container\" data-video-url=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/lXaGPCSqlsM?ps=play&vq=large&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&authuser=0\" data-docid=\"com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftAGHM\">\n</span>\n<img class=\"screenshot clickable\" tabindex=\"0\" itemprop=\"screenshot\" title=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" alt=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" src=\"//lh3.googleusercontent.com/x7dX056Uo1zlIsTx1rN2NO19g3ETS2J-8A6rmrypc-k_VPdMY5hnoFSVS-MENXfUfqBL=h310\" data-expand-to=\"full-screenshot-0\">\n<img class=\"screenshot clickable\" tabindex=\"0\" itemprop=\"screenshot\" title=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" alt=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" src=\"//lh3.googleusercontent.com/iXwUtiXyragrVn6BeQq2OFFeNR0z1JJVaNELuQscWlizBiwn-dGO1Jb9T8UO29NW2DI=h310\" data-expand-to=\"full-screenshot-1\">\n<img class=\"screenshot clickable\" tabindex=\"0\" itemprop=\"screenshot\" title=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" alt=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" src=\"//lh3.googleusercontent.com/ueH3VEOiN414QwlDUtoRE4-xyV1ucHF3puKRXHtMeJFrkqrlAeC_OcVHV3JKGYiKC8A=h310\" data-expand-to=\"full-screenshot-2\">\n<img class=\"screenshot clickable\" tabindex=\"0\" itemprop=\"screenshot\" title=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" alt=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" src=\"//lh3.googleusercontent.com/2VIXmIvny4xxbDVALMUumX4hdIM38P9OHp0PhT0ktFT7CyNcEX22QjpSsI6hQaWRYxM=h310\" data-expand-to=\"full-screenshot-3\">\n<img class=\"screenshot clickable\" tabindex=\"0\" itemprop=\"screenshot\" title=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" alt=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail \" src=\"//lh3.googleusercontent.com/fxSqT5CXu1TmSS2MMjmPXnEXbzIMaBr2mlA3SdA1lRI3rr4IMwPUBHAvS4_UE1uXZN73=h310\" data-expand-to=\"full-screenshot-4\">\n<img class=\"screenshot clickable\" tabindex=\"0\" itemprop=\"screenshot\" title=\" Asphalt Nitro- screenshot thumbnail "
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(test_str, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    print(link.get('src'))
```

Output:

```
//lh3.googleusercontent.com/x7dX056Uo1zlIsTx1rN2NO19g3ETS2J-8A6rmrypc-k_VPdMY5hnoFSVS-MENXfUfqBL=h310
//lh3.googleusercontent.com/iXwUtiXyragrVn6BeQq2OFFeNR0z1JJVaNELuQscWlizBiwn-dGO1Jb9T8UO29NW2DI=h310
//lh3.googleusercontent.com/ueH3VEOiN414QwlDUtoRE4-xyV1ucHF3puKRXHtMeJFrkqrlAeC_OcVHV3JKGYiKC8A=h310
//lh3.googleusercontent.com/2VIXmIvny4xxbDVALMUumX4hdIM38P9OHp0PhT0ktFT7CyNcEX22QjpSsI6hQaWRYxM=h310
//lh3.googleusercontent.com/fxSqT5CXu1TmSS2MMjmPXnEXbzIMaBr2mlA3SdA1lRI3rr4IMwPUBHAvS4_UE1uXZN73=h310
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use regular expressions for parsing HTML. BS4 would be better here.

Comment: @Chuck Logan Lim yes, but no need to install BS4 `pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: @Tim007 this is for particualr app.i want it for all apps.u paased static data in  test_str.